# How to add circle in MapBoxMap flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl-js

I am using `mapbox_gl` package of flutter to display maps...after I show it on my screen, I would like to add circle inside the maps...is there a way to do that... this is the part of the code

```
void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    print(mapController);
    mapController.addListener(_onMapChanged);
    _extractMapInfo();

    mapController.getTelemetryEnabled().then((isEnabled) => setState(() {
          _telemetryEnabled = isEnabled;
        }));
     
    // I have try this code... 
    // mapController.addCircle(
    //   CircleOptions(
    //       geometry: LatLng(....., ....), circleColor: "#FF0000", circleRadius: 200),
    // );
    // but I get error that say:
    // Cannot read property 'add' of null
    //    at mapbox_gl_web.MapboxMapController.new.addCircle 
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

you should add "this" keyword
ex:

```
onMapCreated: (MapboxMapController controller){
          this.controller = controller;
          this.controller.addCircle(
            CircleOptions(
              circleRadius: 100,
              circleColor: '#fff700',
              circleOpacity: 0.5,
              circleStrokeColor: '#fff700',
              circleStrokeOpacity: 1,
              circleStrokeWidth: 5,
              geometry: LatLng(36.8065, 10.1815),
            ),
          );
        },
```